# Parsing JSON with jq to get firstname in below JSON

Tags: shell, jq

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "Alexander",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "middlename": "Johnson",
    "birthyear": 1918,
    "deathyear": 1955,
    "gender": "M",
    "city": "Madison",
    "state": "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Lucy Jo Mary",
    "lastname": "Carrie-Paulson",
    "birthyear": 1967,
    "deathyear": null,
    "gender": "F",
    "city": "Omaha",
    "state": "Nebraska"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Jeremiah",
    "lastname": "Springfield, Jr.",
    "middlename": "Jebediah",
    "birthyear": 1942,
    "deathyear": 2003,
    "gender": "M",
    "city": "Kalamazoo",
    "state": "Michigan"
  }
]
```

How to get **firstname** of the person using **jq** from the above json when there is no **middlename** present in it ?

output: Lucy Jo Mary

Comment: Please edit your question to include the desired output.

Comment: If desired output is “Lucy Jo Mary” then what is the desired output if there are multiple results with no middle name, e.g. if the “Johnson” line is deleted?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - what have you tried so far?

Comment: this _alternative_ solution, based on a _walk-path_ unix utility _jtc_ will work correctly for all cases: when multiple entries w/o `middlename` found, or if `firstname` is missed: **`<file.json jtc -w'<firstname>l:<>f[-1]<middlename>l<>F'`**. If you like, I can elaborate on the utility usage in a separate answer. I'm a developer of the `jtc` tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq -r '.[]|select(.middlename|not).firstname'
```

That gives you the firstnames for the entries that have no `middlename` attribute or where the `middlename` attribute is a boolean `false`.

```
jq -r '.[]|select(has("middlename")|not).firstname'
```

Would give you the firstnames for the entries that have no `middlename`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me.